# Logarithmic Randomness is Necessary for PCP Theorem

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np, probabilistic-algorithms

I am trying to proof the following statement:

If $ {\rm SAT} \in {\rm PCP}[r(n),O(1)]$, where $ r(n)=o(\log n)$, then ${\sf P}={\sf NP}$.

Here are my ideas for the proof:
It can be easily worked from here that there exists an nondeterministic Turing machine $N$ solving any SAT instance in time $o(n^{q})$ for any $q \in R^{+}$. I believe it should lead to a contradiction somewhere  (maybe alteration theorems). I had another approach to guess the certificate, but that takes time $2^{2^{o(\log n)}}$ which is not always polynomially bounded.

Source: [PCP Course By Prahladh Harsha](http://www.tcs.tifr.res.in/~prahladh/teaching/2014-15/limits/psets/pset1.pdf). This was one of the excercise questions. I am self studying this, so this does not violate any ethical arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually show a slightly stronger result: if $SAT \in PCP(o(\log n), o(\log n))$ then P=NP. The idea is to apply the implied reduction repeatedly, reducing the size of the instance all the way down to $O(\log n)$, at which point you can solve it by trying all certificates.

For more details, [Arora and Safra](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/pcp/AS.pdf) (page 76) suggest looking at Theorem 26 in the appendix of [FGLSS](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cis/pubs/shafi/1991-focs-fglss.pdf) ([journal version](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cis/pubs/shafi/1996-jacm.pdf)). Unfortunately, this appendix doesn't seem to be available any more.